# Can you force values into the Date type?

Tags: vb.net, date, leap-year

I've come across a bug where the expedient solution would be to somehow *force* certain values into the `Date` type.

It would include being able to do the following `Dim myDate As Date = New Date(1900, 2, 29)`.

The 29th of February is a leap day but 1900 is not a leap year, therefore, this is not a valid date and it doesn't allow it to even be created. Is there a way you can create it with these values?

Comment: You wrote `1900` in the code sample but wrote `1990` in the text below it. Which number are you wanting to argue for/against or work with?

Comment: The question is, why would you want to do that? For what purpose would an invalid Date-object be for? Answer these questions and someone could come up with an alternative approach.

Comment: I already got an alternative approach, spend the week refactoring a legacy system. Just wondered if it were possible.

Comment: Short answer is "no", but theoretically maybe, not sure. The doc says "The allowable values for year, month, and day depend on calendar. An exception is thrown if the specified date and time cannot be expressed using calendar." So there might be a one hell of a hack by changing the calendar? ;) NOT recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't force an invalid date into a System.DateTime.
Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8

Why don't you use the Date.IsLeapYear(1900) to check which date value you should set?

Here are 2 examples:

```
    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim myYear As Integer = 1900
    If Date.IsLeapYear(myYear) Then
        myDate = New Date(1900, 2, 28)
    Else
        myDate = New Date(1900, 2, 29)
    End If

    Dim myDate2 As Date
    Dim myYear2 As Integer = 1900
    If Date.IsLeapYear(myYear2) Then
        myDate2 = New Date(1900, 3, 1)
    Else
        myDate2 = New Date(1900, 2, 29)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is basically a wrapper around a number.  You can't force an incorrect date into it any more than you can force a bad number into an integer.  Any value it has represents some valid date.  So even if you could use new Date(1900, 2, 30) and not get an exception, the result would not be Feb 30, 1900, but some other valid date.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of fun methods in DateTime.

```
Private Function GetLastDayInFebruary(YearToTest As Integer) As Integer
    Return Date.DaysInMonth(YearToTest, 2)
End Function
```